# how can I get my system timezone on my php server

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

My machine has (GMT +6:00 Astana,Dhaka)  .I set my time zone on my php script

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

But some times it shows wrong date in `date()` function. May be my php server doesn't set GMT time.

But My mysql server catch my machine system timezone. so I need same in php.
Here my database tables outline

```
  SHOP_BALANCE-------------shop_balance_id(PK,AI,INT),shop_balance(DOUBLE),dates(DATE)
  PRODUCT_PURCHASE_ITEM----product_purchase_item_id(PK,AI,INT),product_id(INT),
                           pr_pur_cost_price(DOUBLE),pr_pur_unit_price(DOUBLE),
                           quantity(INT),product_size(INT),dates(TIMESTAMP),
                           bool_check(TINYINT)
  PRODUCT_PURCHASES--------product_purchase_id(PK,AI,INT),insert_operation(INT),
                           product_purchase_item_id(FK ref of PRODUCT_PURCHASE_ITEM).
                           product_id(INT),dates(TIMESTAMP),product_size(INT)
```

> IDEA IS IF DATE MATCH, SHOP BALANCE DECREASING  ON THIS DAY. IF DATE IS NEW DATE TO SHOP BALANCE LAST DATE, SHOP BALANCE ALSO DECREASING BUT INSERT NEW DATE

Here my code

Find last row mysql date on shop_balance table. My dates column is `date` type

```
$query=$this->db->query("select dates from shop_balance order by dates desc limit 1");
$rowfind_last_stock=$query->row();
if(isset($rowfind_last_stock->dates)){
    $find_last_date=$rowfind_stock->dates;
}
```

Find today date  in my php server

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
```

Check date for different query

```
if($find_last_date==$today){
   //run update query 
   $this->db->query(
                   "UPDATE
                      shop_balance AS s
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                     SELECT p.dates,SUM(pr_pur_cost_price*quantity) AS net 
                     FROM product_purchase_item AS i
                     LEFT JOIN product_purchases AS p
                     ON p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
                     WHERE p.insert_operation='$id'
                     GROUP BY p.insert_operation
                    ) AS a
                    ON s.dates=date(a.dates)
                    SET s.shop_balance=s.shop_balance-a.net
                  );"
}
else{
 //run insert query
 $this->db->query(
                   "INSERT INTO shop_balance 
                      SELECT null,
                      (
                       (
                        SELECT shop_balance 
                        FROM shop_balance 
                        ORDER BY shop_balance_id 
                        DESC LIMIT 1
                       )
                      -
                       (
                        SELECT p.dates,SUM(pr_pur_cost_price*quantity) AS net 
                        FROM product_purchase_item AS i
                        LEFT JOIN product_purchases AS p
                        ON p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
                        WHERE p.insert_operation='$id'
                        GROUP BY p.insert_operation             
                       )
                     ),
                     curdate();"
                 );
}
```

The problem is sometimes it perform insert query even same date in php and mysql date when I install different.Both timezone I set above GMT +6.00 . why this problem?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking.  Can you show some more code?  Show how you gather the value, how you pass it to mysql, and what data type it is stored in mysql.  Then we can help better.

Comment: @MattJohnson I update my question. May be you can understand my problem now.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't quite understand the problem. Is the value going into the `dates` field originating from PHP or MySQL?  I can only guess because you didn't show what's going on inside your insert and update routines.  Please try to put a sample together that reproduces the problem in its entirety. Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson please see my update again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html) and for the [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) and [system_time_Zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone) variables.

I believe you will find that your system time zone setting is not what you expect.  When your insert query calls `curdate()`, MySQL delivers it in the time zone from the session's `time_zone` variable.  By default, this will be the same zone that is set in the `system_time_zone` variable.

You can check your time zone variables like this:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone'
```

If you don't want to change the MySQL server's system time zone, then you can set the session time zone by inserting this before your queries:

```sql
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Dhaka';
```

If you get an error, then the time zone tables haven't been loaded.  You can use the [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) to populate them.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18857092/634824).

Of course, a much easier solution would be to not use `curdate()`, and instead gather the current date from PHP and pass it in to query as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function.

```
function currentDate($dateOnly = false, $tillEnd = false)
    {
        // gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000) H i s m d Y
        if($dateOnly)
        {
            if($tillEnd)
            {
                $t = explode('-',date('Y-m-d'));
                return date('Y-m-d',mktime(23, 59, 59, $t[1], $t[2],$t[0]));
            }else{
                return date('Y-m-d');
            }
        }else{
            if($tillEnd)
            {
                $t = explode('-',date('Y-m-d'));
                return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(23, 59, 59, $t[1], $t[2],$t[0]));
            }else{
                return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call this function to get the time of the system.
Arguments are optional, If you want to get the current date with time then call as
eg:

```
$currentDatetime=currentDate();
```

Comment: what is second parameter. please give an example using call you function

Comment: pass true as first parameter

Comment: I don't see how this addresses time zones at all.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since `PHP 5.1.0` (when the `date/time` functions were rewritten), every call to a `date/time` function will generate a `E_NOTICE` if the timezone isn't valid, and/or a `E_WARNING` message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable.

Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your script, you can also use the `INI` setting `date.timezone` to set the default timezone.

Answer (score -1):

**[`time()`](http://www.php.net/time)**

By this you can get time of system

[**Manual**](http://de3.php.net/time)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
echo $tz->getName();
?>
```

Comment: London is only in GMT half of the year.  The other half is in BST.